# Is there any difference between "work at the office" and "work from the office"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *work at the office* and *work from the office*? For example:

> I used to work **at** the office a lot.
>
> I used to work **from** the office a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most often, people would say that they "work **at** the office." This just means that you do all or most of your work in the office.

You would only say that you "work **from** the office" if you want to emphasize that most of your work is interactions with people or systems outside of your office, or that your work is in some sense primarily located outside of the office.  For example:

> Most of my team is in New York, but I work **from** the Boston office.

This says that my work in some sense is mostly far away (with the team in New York), but I am located in the Boston office and I'm doing that work remotely **from** that office.

These days (during Covid-19 lockdowns), many of us are "working **from** home," which emphasizes the fact that all of our co-workers are located elsewhere, and we spend much of our time in video chats, or sending direct messages, or in some other way working with people outside of our homes. Our work's "location" is still in an office somewhere, even if no one is actually in that office during the pandemic.

If you were a professional author, you might say that you "work **at** home," because you are sitting there alone, typing on your computer, instead of interacting with far-away people or with work that is located far away.